# Primefaces dialog always appearing in bottom left corner

Tags: css, primefaces, jsf-2

I have created one primeface dialog in my JSF project. It has below code:

```
<p:dialog id="abc" modal="true" position="center" 
styleClass="pdialog-gen pdialog-gen-height-ext" style="left: 340px !important;"
 draggable="false" closable="true" appendTo="@(body)" dynamic="true"
        resizable="false" widgetVar="ab">
```

It always appears on bottom-left corner. Though I want it to make it appear on center. Even though I have used position attribute, still its appearing on bottom left corner. Could you suggest on this?

Edit1: When I right click on webpage and did "inspect element" to see the code like how it is being rendered in corresponding html, I see below code:

```
    <div id="abc" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow pdialog-gen pdialog-gen-height-ext ui-overlay-visible" 
    style="width: auto; height: auto; left: 0px; top: 341.5px; 
visibility: visible; z-index: 1002;"
     role="dialog" aria-labelledby="abc_title" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="polite">
```

I don't know from where it is picking inline-style. Can anyone suggest on this?

**Edit-2**
I got to know the solution. I wrote a CSS style for #abc where i defined left:240px; the solved my proble. Thread closed. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to remove `left: 340px !important;`

and apply its container `margin: 0 auto;` this will make it center

Answer (score 0):

The `p:dialog` appears to center as default settings.
Where do you have put the `<p:dialog>` tag?
Could be the style class:

```
styleClass="pdialog-gen pdialog-gen-height-ext"
```

Comment: Are you not able to see <p:dialog> tag?

Comment: you insert it as child of another component? Can you try to drop styleCass and style attributes?

Comment: Faoucault: yes I tried to drop style and styleClass attribute, that resulted into disappearing in dialog box. I have edited my question and provided more details on it. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I know about two reasons that make this issue.

1. Using JQuery-UI, it makes conflicts with Primefaces's library.
2. Using Richfaces with Primefaces can make this issue too.